# How do I get a list of functions/methods/properties from a DLL?

Tags: powershell, dll

I have been "Dev Neutered" for a long time now and know enough powershell but not enough to solve this problem...

my kids have asked if I can write a script that returns the date of an event in a game and that game has an interface DLL that has the commands but I don't know what it is called or what is properties are.

So I was wondering if I can get some help on this.  Basically I want to get a list of methods I can call and what the parameters required and what the results returned would be.

a Sample Powershell would be awesome!  the DLL in question can be found at "https://7dtd.illy.bz/wiki/Server%20fixes"

thanks a ton!!

Comment: If the DLL is unmanaged, this can't be done. An unmanaged DLL exports the names of its functions, but not their signatures; that requires a header file. If the DLL is managed, it can be done, but PowerShell is not the most convenient way -- that would be a dedicated metadata viewer like ILSpy.

Comment: That's a link to an entire game, not one dll. You might get more response if you focus on the dll you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

you can use these applications ( both free)

- ILSpy:  https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/ilspy/9MXFBKFVSQ13
- dotPeek:  https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).